# Who cut the cheese?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, acrostic

StackOverflow is celebrating it's $10^{th}$ anniversary and thus created an [article on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese) about it. I decided to write a simple riddle in response to their post, and figured I would also share it here for the community.

---

> Colorado is known as my cat.
>
> He's not fond of pepper in fact.
>
> Excitement takes over,
>
> Each time you come over.
>
> So stop by the cottage with Jack.
>
> ---
>
> Easy now Colby, you'll eat here for free, just
>
> String up the nachos for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial Answer:

> Cheeses identified: Pepperjack Cheese, Cat Milk Cheese, Cottage Cheese, Colby Cheese, and String Cheese, Nacho Cheese.
>  Acrostic: Cheeses

Comment: The Colorado one is wrong but everything else is correct lol

Comment: How am I supposed to answer it fully?

Comment: The Colorado cheese can be found on the wiki in United States cheeses lol

Comment: So that was the Colorado part answer?

Comment: Fromage de Chat?

Comment: I was also thinking that, but did not include that in my answer but I will now :)